# Maximo Anywhere Multi language support issue

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

I am using Maximo Anywhere 7.5.2 (Work Execution) App. I added a new folder for a new language (Ex: AB) under translation/nls/AB, after deploying the app. App should load the label data from AB but it always load as "English" only.

```
<echo>Copying generated artifact en over real translation</echo>
            <copy file="${application.home}/common/js/generated/application/translation/nls/artifact.js" tofile="${application.home}/common/js/application/translation/nls/artifact.js"/>
            <echo>Copying artifact en to en-gb to support UK</echo>
            <copy file="${application.home}/common/js/application/translation/nls/artifact.js" tofile="${application.home}/common/js/application/translation/nls/AB/artifact.js"/>
```

Note: If I copy nls/AB/artifact.js directly to nls/artifact.js.Pl help

Comment: I understand that Anywhere translation is based on device language settings (iPhone) but If I need to add a new language(supported in iPhone already) which is not in default anywhere translation, what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to be able to do this yourself as a customization.   There are lots of pieces along the way that also need to support the new language.  The Dojo build, and dojo libraries, the native Android or iOS messages, the worklight/mobilefirst strings (which we also translate and override in a different way).

But just to give you a little more information about how Javascript handles translations, if you open up the main artifact.js file, at the bottom, you'll see a list of langcode and locales with true or false, to indicate whether to try and load that language or not.  You'll need to add your custom language there, set to true, change your main browser language to that language and then try in chrome simulator.

Can you wait for a potential enhancement request to support this language?